# Linq Min in Select new & Multiple GroupBy columns

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework, linq

I want to write following query in `Linq`

```sql
INSERT INTO INOUTNEW (CODE,INDATE,TIME_DATE1,INOUTFLAG,TIME_FLD1,TIME_FLD2,TIME_FLD3) 
SELECT CODE,MIN(INDATE),TIME_DATE1,'I',TIME_FLD1,TIME_FLD2,'31/05/2015' FROM INOUT 
WHERE TIME_FLD1='T0003' AND INDATE >= '31/05/2015' AND INDATE <= '31/05/2015' 
AND TIME_DATE1='31/05/2015' 
GROUP BY CODE,TIME_DATE1,TIME_FLD1,TIME_FLD2
```

SO I am trying this :-

```
var data = ctx.tblInOut.Where(m => m.CompanyId == companyId && m.Time_Field1 == item.ShiftCode && m.InDate == StrInStart && m.InDate <= StrInEnd && m.Time_Date1 == InputDate).Select(m =>
                            new
                            {
                                EmployeeId = m.EmployeeId,
                                InDate = Min(m.InDate),
                                Time_Date1 = m.Time_Date1,
                                InOutFlag = m.InOutFlag    
                            }).ToList();
```

I am stuck in `Min` Part. How to get `Min` in Select? And How to add multiple `GroupBy` in Linq?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
var data = ctx.tblInOut
.Where(m => 
    m.CompanyId == companyId && 
    m.Time_Field1 == item.ShiftCode && 
    m.InDate == StrInStart && 
    m.InDate <= StrInEnd && 
    m.Time_Date1 == InputDate
)
.GroupBy(m =>
    new {
        m.Code,
        m.Time_Date1,
        m.Time_FLD1,
        m.Time_FLD2
})
.Select(g =>
new
{
    m.Key.Code,
    InDate = m.Min(gg => gg.InDate),
    m.Key.Time_Date1,
    Something = "I",
    m.Key.Time_FLD1,
    m.Key.Time_FLD2,
    SomeDate = "31/05/2015"
}).ToList();
```

To get `Min`, you must group first - otherwise it's trying to call `Min` on a single element.

`.Key` simply references the key of the group (in this case, a tuple of Code, Date1, Time_FLD1, Time_FLD2)

Comment: Getting error :- `; Expected` here :- ` m.Time_Field1, m.Time_Field2 }`

Comment: I think you dont need a `return` inside `group by`.

Comment: @Anup See my edit - note though, I haven't tested it for syntax errors, since I don't have your data model set up.

Comment: Now i am getting error at `g` here :- `.Select(g =>` `Cannot convert lambda expression to type string because it is not a delegate type`

Comment: Change `Select(g => ` to `Select(m => `